# Use of PUT vs PATCH methods in REST API real life scenarios

Tags: json, rest, http, put, http-method

First of all, some definitions:

PUT is defined in [Section 9.6 RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6):

> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing resource, the enclosed entity **SHOULD be considered as a modified version of the one residing on the origin server**. If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the origin server can create the resource with that URI.

PATCH is defined in [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789):

> The PATCH method requests that **a set of changes** described in the
> request entity be applied to the resource identified by the Request-
> URI.

Also according to [RFC 2616 Section 9.1.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.2) PUT is Idempotent while PATCH is not.

Now let us take a look at a real example. When I do POST to `/users` with the data `{username: 'skwee357', email: 'skwee357@domain.example'}` and the server is capable of creating a resource, it will respond with 201 and resource location (lets assume `/users/1`) and any next call to GET `/users/1` will return `{id: 1, username: 'skwee357', email: 'skwee357@domain.example'}`.

Now let us say I want to modify my email. Email modification is considered "a set of changes" and therefore I should PATCH `/users/1` with "[patch document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2)". In my case it would be the JSON document: `{email: 'skwee357@newdomain.example'}`. The server then returns 200 (assuming permission are ok). This brings me to first question:

- PATCH is NOT idempotent. It said so in RFC 2616 and RFC 5789. However if I issue the same PATCH request (with my new email), I will get the same resource state (with my email being modified to the requested value). Why is PATCH not then idempotent?

PATCH is a relatively new verb (RFC introduced in March 2010), and it comes to solve the problem of "patching" or modifying a set of fields. Before PATCH was introduced, everybody used PUT to update resources. But after PATCH was introduced, it leaves me confused about what PUT is used for. And this brings me to my second (and the main) question:

- What is the real difference between PUT and PATCH? I have read somewhere that PUT might be used to **replace** entire entity under specific resource, so one should send the full entity (instead of set of attributes as with PATCH). What is the real practical usage for such case? When would you like to replace / overwrite an entity at a specific resource URI and why is such an operation not considered updating / patching the entity? The only practical use case I see for PUT is issuing a PUT on a collection, i.e. `/users` to replace the entire collection. Issuing PUT on a specific entity makes no sense after PATCH was introduced. Am I wrong?

Comment: a) it's RFC 2616, not 2612. b) RFC 2616 has been obsoleted, the current spec of PUT is in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#PUT, c) I don't get your question; isn't it pretty obvious that PUT can be used to replace any resource, not only a collection, d) before PATCH was introduced, people usually used POST, e) finally, yes, a *specific* PATCH request (depending on the patch format) *can* be idempotent; it's just that it's not generally.

Comment: if it helps I've wrote an article on the PATCH vs PUT http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/36-patch-vs-put-and-the-patch-json-syntax-war

Comment: Simple: POST creates an item in a collection. PUT replaces an item. PATCH modifies an item. When POSTing, the URL for the new item is computed and returned in the response, whereas PUT and PATCH require a URL in the request. Right?

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5789#section-2 PATCH is not idempotent.

Comment: @equivalent8 the link no longer points to the article, I'm afraid

Comment: sorry @theking2 the url has changed it suppose to be  https://blog.eq8.eu/article/put-vs-patch.html

Comment: Also, can someone share time analysis of both the methods? I mean how much faster is it to make a PATCH vs PUT request in a real-life scenario in terms of the time it takes to make those requests?

Answer (score 1589, accepted):

**NOTE**: When I first spent time reading about REST, idempotence was a confusing concept to try to get right. I still didn't get it quite right in my original answer, as further comments (and [Jason Hoetger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338329/2449905)) have shown. For a while, I have resisted updating this answer extensively, to avoid effectively plagiarizing Jason, but I'm editing it now because, well, I was asked to (in the comments).

After reading my answer, I suggest you also read [Jason Hoetger's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338329/2449905) to this question, and I will try to make my answer better without simply stealing from Jason.

### Why is PUT idempotent?

As you noted in your RFC 2616 citation, PUT is considered idempotent. When you PUT a resource, these two assumptions are in play:

1. You are referring to an entity, not to a collection.
2. The entity you are supplying is complete (the *entire* entity).

Let's look at one of your examples.

```json
{ "username": "skwee357", "email": "skwee357@domain.example" }
```

If you POST this document to `/users`, as you suggest, then you might get back an entity such as

```json
## /users/1

{
    "username": "skwee357",
    "email": "skwee357@domain.example"
}
```

If you want to modify this entity later, you choose between PUT and PATCH. A PUT might look like this:

```json
PUT /users/1
{
    "username": "skwee357",
    "email": "skwee357@gmail.com"       // new email address
}
```

You can accomplish the same using PATCH. That might look like this:

```json
PATCH /users/1
{
    "email": "skwee357@gmail.com"       // new email address
}
```

You'll notice a difference right away between these two. The PUT included all of the parameters on this user, but PATCH only included the one that was being modified (`email`).

When using PUT, it is assumed that you are sending the complete entity, and that complete entity *replaces* any existing entity at that URI. In the above example, the PUT and PATCH accomplish the same goal: they both change this user's email address. But PUT handles it by replacing the entire entity, while PATCH only updates the fields that were supplied, leaving the others alone.

Since PUT requests include the entire entity, if you issue the same request repeatedly, it should always have the same outcome (the data you sent is now the entire data of the entity). Therefore PUT is idempotent.

### Using PUT wrong

What happens if you use the above PATCH data in a PUT request?

```json
GET /users/1
{
    "username": "skwee357",
    "email": "skwee357@domain.example"
}
PUT /users/1
{
    "email": "skwee357@gmail.com"       // new email address
}

GET /users/1
{
    "email": "skwee357@gmail.com"      // new email address... and nothing else!
}
```

(I'm assuming for the purposes of this question that the server doesn't have any specific required fields, and would allow this to happen... that may not be the case in reality.)

Since we used PUT, but only supplied `email`, now that's the only thing in this entity. This has resulted in data loss.

This example is here for illustrative purposes -- don't ever actually do this (unless your intent is to drop the omitted fields, of course... then you are using PUT as it should be used). This PUT request is technically idempotent, but that doesn't mean it isn't a terrible, broken idea.

### How can PATCH be idempotent?

In the above example, PATCH *was* idempotent. You made a change, but if you made the same change again and again, it would always give back the same result: you changed the email address to the new value.

```json
GET /users/1
{
    "username": "skwee357",
    "email": "skwee357@domain.example"
}
PATCH /users/1
{
    "email": "skwee357@gmail.com"       // new email address
}

GET /users/1
{
    "username": "skwee357",
    "email": "skwee357@gmail.com"       // email address was changed
}
PATCH /users/1
{
    "email": "skwee357@gmail.com"       // new email address... again
}

GET /users/1
{
    "username": "skwee357",
    "email": "skwee357@gmail.com"       // nothing changed since last GET
}
```

### My original example, fixed for accuracy

I originally had examples that I thought were showing non-idempotency, but they were misleading / incorrect. I am going to keep the examples, but use them to illustrate a different thing: that multiple PATCH documents against the same entity, modifying different attributes, do not make the PATCHes non-idempotent.

Let's say that at some past time, a user was added. This is the state that you are starting from.

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Sam Kwee",
  "email": "skwee357@olddomain.example",
  "address": "123 Mockingbird Lane",
  "city": "New York",
  "state": "NY",
  "zip": "10001"
}
```

After a PATCH, you have a modified entity:

```json
PATCH /users/1
{"email": "skwee357@newdomain.example"}

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Sam Kwee",
  "email": "skwee357@newdomain.example",    // the email changed, yay!
  "address": "123 Mockingbird Lane",
  "city": "New York",
  "state": "NY",
  "zip": "10001"
}
```

If you then repeatedly apply your PATCH, you will continue to get the same result: the email was changed to the new value. A goes in, A comes out, therefore this is idempotent.

An hour later, after you have gone to make some coffee and take a break, someone else comes along with their own PATCH. It seems the Post Office has been making some changes.

```json
PATCH /users/1
{"zip": "12345"}

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Sam Kwee",
  "email": "skwee357@newdomain.example",  // still the new email you set
  "address": "123 Mockingbird Lane",
  "city": "New York",
  "state": "NY",
  "zip": "12345"                      // and this change as well
}
```

Since this PATCH from the post office doesn't concern itself with email, only zip code, if it is repeatedly applied, it will also get the same result: the zip code is set to the new value. A goes in, A comes out, therefore this is *also* idempotent.

The next day, you decide to send your PATCH again.

```json
PATCH /users/1
{"email": "skwee357@newdomain.example"}

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Sam Kwee",
  "email": "skwee357@newdomain.example",
  "address": "123 Mockingbird Lane",
  "city": "New York",
  "state": "NY",
  "zip": "12345"
}
```

Your patch has the same effect it had yesterday: it set the email address. A went in, A came out, therefore this is idempotent as well.

### What I got wrong in my original answer

I want to draw an important distinction (something I got wrong in my original answer). Many servers will respond to your REST requests by sending back the new entity state, with your modifications (if any). So, when you get this *response* back, it is different *from the one you got back yesterday*, because the zip code is not the one you received last time. However, your request was not concerned with the zip code, only with the email. So your PATCH document is still idempotent - the email you sent in PATCH is now the email address on the entity.

### So when is PATCH not idempotent, then?

For a full treatment of this question, I again refer you to [Jason Hoetger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338329/2449905) which already fully answers that.

Comment: This sentence isn't quite correct: "But it is idempotent: whenever A goes in, B always comes out". For example, if you were to `GET /users/1` before the Post Office updated the zip code and then again make the same `GET /users/1` request after the Post Office's update, you would get two different responses (different zip codes). The same "A" (GET request) is going in, but you're getting different results. Yet GET is still idempotent.

Comment: @JasonHoetger GET is safe (presumed to cause no change), but is not always idempotent. There is a difference. See [RFC 2616 sec. 9.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Comment: @DanLowe: GET most definitely is guaranteed to be idempotent. It says exactly that in Section 9.1.2 of RFC 2616, and in the updated spec, [RFC 7231 section 4.2.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.2.2), that "Of the request methods defined by this specification, PUT, DELETE, and safe request methods are idempotent." Idempotence just doesn't mean "you get the same response every time you make the same request". 7231 4.2.2 goes on to say: "Repeating the request will have the same intended effect, even if the original request succeeded, **though the response might differ.**"

Comment: @JasonHoetger I'll concede that, but I don't see what it has to do with this answer, which discussed PUT and PATCH and never even mentions GET...

Comment: @DanLowe: My point was that the definition of idempotence in your answer was incorrect, and that the PATCH in your example is actually idempotent. I added an answer that includes an example of a non-idempotent PATCH.

Comment: @JasonHoetger I suppose it depends what result you are considering. Your point is that the _overall state_ isn't changed as a result of the patch, whereas I was demonstrating the _returned result_ differs between one request and a later request.

Comment: @DanLowe Very nicely explained !

Comment: I agree with @JasonHoetger here - Dan's answer is certainly 'nice' and has some nice examples. But, ultimately, it is completely incorrect in terms of answering the question and its definition of idempotent.

Comment: Can this answer please be updated to remove or alter the statements like "it is idempotent: whenever A goes in, B always comes out." As others have pointed out these statements can be reasonably construed as an attempt to define "idempotent" in the context of a RESTful API. When taken as an attempt to define, this statement is simply incorrect (idempotence makes claims about input repetition, the definition shows a relationship to outputs that is not guaranteed). This is the top answer on a highly visible question. It is teaching newcomers to REST the incorrect definition of an important term.

Comment: @DanLowe - I think this is great! 1000 hats off to you for having the humility to update the answer.

Comment: "This PUT request is technically idempotent" - yes but it's sending the wrong data (ie missing data) that's the point. Good piece.

Comment: What I think is that most people are making a mistake thinking that PUT/PATCH applies to the response somehow, when it actually applies to the request. What you are stating using the idempotent PUT method (a=5) is that your request can be repeated numerous times, having the same (constant) state change applied to the resource. If you use the non-idempotent PATCH method (a=a+5), you state that your request for change is of a dynamic nature and it matters how many times you perform it.

Comment: The typical example for PUT/PATCH difference is when you buy something on ebay for example and after clicking the buy button the page doesn't refresh, so what do you do? Clicking the buy button again would do what exactly? Will it just re-commit the same purchasing transaction (PUT) or will it buy another item (POST/PATCH). Looking at the method used, when the buy button is clicked, should answer this question.

Comment: 2 different requests updating different attributes is given to show that PATCH is indeed idempotent? Doesn't idempotent mean *the same* request?

Comment: Ah, the comment from @JasonHoetger cleared it up: only the resulting states, rather than responses, of multiple idempotent method requests need be identical.

Comment: PATCH /api/v1/users/change_pw 204 93.520 ms - -
PATCH /api/v1/users/change_pw 204 82.513 ms - -
PATCH /api/v1/users/change_pw 204 80.690 ms - -
PATCH /api/v1/users/change_pw 204 79.999 ms - -

PUT /api/v1/users/change_pw 204 1.194 ms - -
PUT /api/v1/users/change_pw 204 0.382 ms - -
PUT /api/v1/users/change_pw 204 0.332 ms - -
PUT /api/v1/users/change_pw 204 0.350 ms - -
PUT /api/v1/users/change_pw 204 0.349 ms - -
PUT /api/v1/users/change_pw 204 0.326 ms - -

and also the speed... but it won't actually matter since it is very small

Comment: @DanLowe On section "Using PUT wrong". Why is this supposed to be wrong, terrible and broken? Why not doing this? When sending only a set of parameter with PUT, I **intend** implicitly the removal of values from the missing parameters. Why should I do the effort to blow up my request with 10 or 20+ paramers with empty values?

Comment: @fabpico It's not broken if the intent is to drop the omitted parameters from the record. That's exactly how PUT is intended to be used, as noted in the answer: "The entity you are supplying is **complete (the entire entity)**."

Comment: @fabpico I updated the answer to try to make that more clear to future readers

Answer (score 580):

Though Dan Lowe's excellent answer very thoroughly answered the OP's question about the difference between PUT and PATCH, its answer to the question of why PATCH is not idempotent is not quite correct.

To show why PATCH isn't idempotent, it helps to start with the definition of idempotence (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning)):

> The term idempotent is used more comprehensively to describe an operation that will produce the same results if executed once or multiple times [...] An idempotent function is one that has the property f(f(x)) = f(x) for any value x.

In more accessible language, an idempotent PATCH could be defined as: After PATCHing a resource with a patch document, all subsequent PATCH calls to the same resource with the same patch document will not change the resource.

Conversely, a non-idempotent operation is one where f(f(x)) != f(x), which for PATCH could be stated as: After PATCHing a resource with a patch document, subsequent PATCH calls to the same resource with the same patch document **do** change the resource.

To illustrate a non-idempotent PATCH, suppose there is a /users resource, and suppose that calling `GET /users` returns a list of users, currently:

```
[{ "id": 1, "username": "firstuser", "email": "firstuser@example.org" }]
```

Rather than PATCHing /users/{id}, as in the OP's example, suppose the server allows PATCHing /users. Let's issue this PATCH request:

```
PATCH /users
[{ "op": "add", "username": "newuser", "email": "newuser@example.org" }]
```

Our patch document instructs the server to add a new user called `newuser` to the list of users. After calling this the first time, `GET /users` would return:

```
[{ "id": 1, "username": "firstuser", "email": "firstuser@example.org" },
 { "id": 2, "username": "newuser", "email": "newuser@example.org" }]
```

Now, if we issue the *exact same* PATCH request as above, what happens? (For the sake of this example, let's assume that the /users resource allows duplicate usernames.) The "op" is "add", so a new user is added to the list, and a subsequent `GET /users` returns:

```
[{ "id": 1, "username": "firstuser", "email": "firstuser@example.org" },
 { "id": 2, "username": "newuser", "email": "newuser@example.org" },
 { "id": 3, "username": "newuser", "email": "newuser@example.org" }]
```

The /users resource has changed *again*, even though we issued the *exact same* PATCH against the *exact same* endpoint. If our PATCH is f(x), f(f(x)) is not the same as f(x), and therefore, **this particular PATCH is not idempotent**.

Although PATCH isn't *guaranteed* to be idempotent, there's nothing in the PATCH specification to prevent you from making all PATCH operations on your particular server idempotent. RFC 5789 even anticipates advantages from idempotent PATCH requests:

> A PATCH request can be issued in such a way as to be idempotent,
>      which also helps prevent bad outcomes from collisions between two
>      PATCH requests on the same resource in a similar time frame.

In Dan's example, his PATCH operation is, in fact, idempotent. In that example, the /users/1 entity changed between our PATCH requests, but not *because of* our PATCH requests; it was actually the Post Office's *different* patch document that caused the zip code to change. The Post Office's different PATCH is a different operation; if our PATCH is f(x), the Post Office's PATCH is g(x). Idempotence states that `f(f(f(x))) = f(x)`, but makes no guarantes about `f(g(f(x)))`.

Comment: Assuming that the server also allows issuing PUT at `/users`, this would make PUT non-idempotent as well. All this comes down to is how the server is designed to handle requests.

Comment: @UzairSajid - PATCH and PUT are independent. Issuing a PUT to /users should always be idempotent, and if it is not, the server is non-compliant.

Comment: So, We could build an API only with PATCH operations. Then, what becomes the REST principle of using http VERBS to make CRUD actions on Resources ? Aren't we overcomplexifying the PATCH borders gentlemen here ?

Comment: If PUT is implemented on a collection (e.g. `/users`), any PUT request should replace the contents of that collection. So a PUT to `/users` should expect a collection of users and delete all others. This is idempotent. It isn't likely you'd do such a thing on a /users endpoint. But something like `/users/1/emails` may be a collection and it may be perfectly valid to allow replacing the entire collection with a new one.

Comment: Though this answer provides a great example of idempotence, I believe this may muddy the waters in typical REST scenarios. In this case you have a PATCH request with an additional `op` action that is triggering specific server side logic. This would require server and client to be aware of the specific values to pass for the `op` field to trigger server side workflows. In more straightforward REST scenarios, this type of `op` functionality is bad practice and should likely be handled directly through HTTP verbs.

Comment: I would never consider issuing a PATCH, only POST and DELETE, against a collection. Is this really ever done? Can PATCH therefore be considered idempotent for all practical purposes?

Comment: Perhaps my last comment reiterated at least part of the very informative one by @ivandov

Comment: I don't think relying on Wikipedia's mathematical definition of idempotence helps a lot here (although I love mathematics). The RFC defines idempotence in a much more pragmatic way, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53319895/10608322) below.

Comment: Totally agree with @bohr here, PATCH can easily be abused. I suggest to read the article [Please. Don't Patch Like An Idiot.](https://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/) by William Durand and the [RFC 7396](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7396). Sadly HTTP is a giant mess and REST on top of it doesn't make it bearable.

Comment: But why would you use PATCH to add a user to the users collection? You're basically creating a new resource (new user), shouldn't that be done with a POST request? This confuses me.

Comment: @DFSFOT It makes sense only if the collection itself (e.g. users) is considered a resource/entity

Comment: This example doesn't really follow proper RESTful semantics.  The collection wouldn't be appended to with either a PATCH or a PUT, but a POST.  The demonstrated `PATCH /users [{ "op": "add", ...` operation is really a `POST /users` in disguise.  I would re-design this API and avoid anything resembling RPC-in-JSON semantics.

Comment: Note that if you're modifying something with a fixed set of fields/members/part/columns, modifying a single field/etc. _is_ idempotent: it's override a whole thing (inside a thing) with a new whole thing. The problem comes with collections that can have a varying number of members. Operations that add a new member can never be idempotent, and operations that increment an integer (such as the collection's size) can likewise never be idempotent: if f(x) = x + c and f(f(x)) = f(x) then (x+c)+c = x+c so c=0. TL;DR: maps, tuples and records can be okay, array(List)s and std::vector cannot.

Comment: Another example of a non-idempotent PATCH is when storing how many points a user has. For example, if this was the original document: `{"username": "bob", "points": 3}`, and you wanted to increase his score by 2, there are two approaches:

with a PATCH, you might do something like this: `{"points": {"op": "add", "amount": 2}`. This is NOT idempotent since if you do the same patch again, the score will change from 5 to 7.

An idempotent version using PUT would be the following: `{"username": "bob", "points": 5}`. No matter how many times you run this, the score will be 5.

Comment: HTTP Verbs concepts and definitions stand alone. REST is just an architectural style. Now, if the OP asked how to implement PATCH operations in a RESTful way, then some of these comments might make sense. The thing is just that people mix ups these concepts all the time when they are not necessarily related.

Answer (score 195):

### TLDR - Dumbed Down Version

**PUT** => Set all new attributes for an existing resource.

**PATCH** => Partially update an existing resource (not all attributes required).

Comment: Additionally: PATCH => could be instructions rather than just the updated properties

Comment: Why would we send ALL the attributes for an existing resource if the gal is simple to update ? why is it important to check that ? and not simply update fields that are sent ?

Comment: `PUT` does not require the resource to be existing. While it's a common pattern to use `POST` to create and `PUT` to update, the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-put) says "The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message content." You could very well design an API so that `PUT /users/1 HTTP/1.1` will create the user with ID 1 if it does not exist, and replace the user with ID 1 if it does.

Answer (score 98):

I was curious about this as well and found a few interesting articles. I may not answer your question to its full extent, but this at least provides some more information.

http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html

> The HTTP RFC specifies that PUT must take a full new resource
> representation as the request entity. This means that if for example
> only certain attributes are provided, those should be remove (i.e. set
> to null).

Given that, then a PUT should send the entire object. For instance,

```
/users/1
PUT {id: 1, username: 'skwee357', email: 'newemail@domain.example'}
```

This would effectively update the email. The reason PUT may not be too effective is that your only really modifying one field and including the username is kind of useless. The next example shows the difference.

```
/users/1
PUT {id: 1, email: 'newemail@domain.example'}
```

Now, if the PUT was designed according the spec, then the PUT would set the username to null and you would get the following back.

```
{id: 1, username: null, email: 'newemail@domain.example'}
```

When you use a PATCH, you only update the field you specify and leave the rest alone as in your example.

The following take on the PATCH is a little different than I have never seen before.

http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/

> The difference between the PUT and PATCH requests is reflected in the
> way the server processes the enclosed entity to modify the resource
> identified by the Request-URI. In a PUT request, the enclosed entity
> is considered to be a modified version of the resource stored on the
> origin server, and the client is requesting that the stored version be
> replaced. With PATCH, however, the enclosed entity contains a set of
> instructions describing how a resource currently residing on the
> origin server should be modified to produce a new version. The PATCH
> method affects the resource identified by the Request-URI, and it also
> MAY have side effects on other resources; i.e., new resources may be
> created, or existing ones modified, by the application of a PATCH.

```
PATCH /users/123

[
    { "op": "replace", "path": "/email", "value": "new.email@example.org" }
]
```

You are more or less treating the PATCH as a way to update a field. So instead of sending over the partial object, you're sending over the operation. i.e. Replace email with value.

The article ends with this.

> It is worth mentioning that PATCH is not really designed for truly REST
> APIs, as Fielding's dissertation does not define any way to partially
> modify resources. But, Roy Fielding himself said that PATCH was
> something [he] created for the initial HTTP/1.1 proposal because
> partial PUT is never RESTful. Sure you are not transferring a complete
> representation, but REST does not require representations to be
> complete anyway.

Now, I don't know if I particularly agree with the article as many commentators point out. Sending over a partial representation can easily be a description of the changes.

For me, I am mixed on using PATCH. For the most part, I will treat PUT as a PATCH since the only real difference I have noticed so far is that PUT "should" set missing values to null. It may not be the 'most correct' way to do it, but good luck coding perfect.

Comment: It may be worth adding: in William Durand's article (and rfc 6902) there are examples where "op" is "add". This is obviously not idempotent.

Comment: Or you can make easier and use the RFC 7396 Merge Patch instead and avoid building patch JSON.

Comment: for nosql tables, differences between patch and put is important, because nosql have no columns

Answer (score 67):

### tl;dr version

- **POST**: is used to *create* an entity
- **PUT**: is used to update/replace an existing entity where you *must send the entire representation* of the entity as you wish for it to be stored
- **PATCH**: is used to *update* an entity where you *send only the fields that need to be updated*

Comment: Why is it important to send ALL fields for an update ?

Comment: @jossefaz because you want to replace the entire resource.

Comment: So do you think that we can update your answer for the PUT to "is used to update/replace an existing entity" ?

Comment: Thanks @jossefaz, I updated my answer

Comment: Short and to the point = just how we want it here. Should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: So is PUT a special case of a PATCH where the only difference is that PUT includes a complete set where PATCH is allowed to have a subset of a representation?

Answer (score 33):

The difference between PUT and PATCH is that:

1. PUT is required to be idempotent. In order to achieve that, you have to put the entire complete resource in the request body.
2. PATCH can be non-idempotent. Which implies it can also be idempotent in some cases, such as the cases you described.

PATCH requires some "patch language" to tell the server how to modify the resource. The caller and the server need to define some "operations" such as "add", "replace", "delete". For example:

```
GET /contacts/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Sam Kwee",
  "email": "skwee357@olddomain.example",
  "state": "NY",
  "zip": "10001"
}

PATCH /contacts/1
{
 [{"operation": "add", "field": "address", "value": "123 main street"},
  {"operation": "replace", "field": "email", "value": "abc@myemail.example"},
  {"operation": "delete", "field": "zip"}]
}

GET /contacts/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Sam Kwee",
  "email": "abc@myemail.example",
  "state": "NY",
  "address": "123 main street",
}
```

Instead of using explicit "operation" fields, the patch language can make it implicit by defining conventions like:

in the PATCH request body:

1. The existence of a field means "replace" or "add" that field.
2. If the value of a field is null, it means delete that field.

With the above convention, the PATCH in the example can take the following form:

```
PATCH /contacts/1
{
  "address": "123 main street",
  "email": "abc@myemail.example",
  "zip":
}
```

Which looks more concise and user-friendly. But the users need to be aware of the underlying convention.

With the operations I mentioned above, the PATCH is still idempotent. But if you define operations like: "increment" or "append", you can easily see it won't be idempotent anymore.

Answer (score 8):

In my humble opinion, idempotence means:

- PUT:

I send a compete resource definition, so - the resulting resource state is exactly as defined by PUT params. Each and every time I update the resource with the same PUT params - the resulting state is exactly the same.

- PATCH:

I sent only part of the resource definition, so it might happen other users are updating this resource's OTHER parameters in a meantime. Consequently - consecutive patches with the same parameters and their values might result with different resource state. For instance:

Presume an object defined as follows:

```
CAR:
 - color: black,
 - type: sedan,
 - seats: 5
```

I patch it with:

```
{color: 'red'}
```

The resulting object is:

```
CAR:
 - color: red,
 - type: sedan,
 - seats: 5
```

Then, some other users patches this car with:

```
{type: 'hatchback'}
```

so, the resulting object is:

```
CAR:
 - color: red,
 - type: hatchback,
 - seats: 5
```

Now, if I patch this object again with:

```
{color: 'red'}
```

the resulting object is:

```
CAR:
 - color: red,
 - type: hatchback,
 - seats: 5
```

What is DIFFERENT to what I've got previously!

This is why PATCH is not idempotent while PUT is idempotent.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338329/10376320 for why this situation is not related to idempotence

Answer (score 5):

I might be a bit off topic considering your questions about idempotency, but I'd like you to consider evolutivity.

Consider you have the following element :

```
{
  "username": "skwee357",
  "email": "skwee357@domain.example"
}
```

If you modify with PUT, you have to give the whole representation of the object :

```
PUT /users/1
{
  "username": "skwee357",
  "email": "skwee357@newdomain.example"
}
```

Now you update the schema, and add a field `phone` :

```
PUT /users/1
{
  "username": "skwee357",
  "email": "skwee357@newdomain.example",
  "phone": "123-456-7890"
}
```

Now update it again with PUT the same way, it will set `phone` to null. To avoid that bad side-effect, you have to update all the components that modify elements everytime you update your schema. Lame.

By using PATCH, you do not have this problem, because PATCH only updates the given fields. So, in my opinion, you should use PATCH to modify an element (whether it is *really* idempotent or not). That's a real-life return of experience.

Answer (score 4):

## TLDR;

**POST** ➔ Creates a resource (**NOT IDEMPOTENT** - calling multiple time the same API can conflict with already existing resource)

**PUT** ➔ Updates a resource entirely - all attributes should be provided (**IDEMPOTENT** - can be called multiple time safely, because the resource will be replaced entirely)

**PATCH** ➔ Update an existing resource partially - only needed attributes should be provided (**NOT IDEMPOTENT** - calling multiple times can alter the original resource. Ex. update an array with new element will always increase the array, while put will replace it with what is provided.
Another drawback of PATCH is that it needs to support a new logic, a contract on how to update only some fields.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone else has answered the PUT vs PATCH.  I was just going to answer what part of the title of the original question asks: "... in REST API real life scenarios".  In the real world, this happened to me with internet application that had a RESTful server and a relational database with a Customer table that was "wide" (about 40 columns).  I mistakenly used PUT but had assumed it was like a SQL Update command and had not filled out all the columns. Problems: 1) Some columns were optional (so blank was valid answer), 2) many columns rarely changed, 3) some columns the user was not allowed to change such as time stamp of Last Purchase Date, 4) one column was a free-form text "Comments" column that users diligently filled with half-page customer services comments like spouses name to ask about OR usual order, 5) I was working on an internet app at time and there was worry about packet size.

The disadvantage of PUT is that it forces you to send a large packet of info (all columns including the entire Comments column, even though only a few things changed) AND multi-user issue of 2+ users editing the same customer simultaneously (so last one to press Update wins). The disadvantage of PATCH is that you have to keep track on the view/screen side of what changed and have some intelligence to send only the parts that changed.  Patch's multi-user issue is limited to editing the same column(s) of same customer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me quote and comment more closely the [RFC 7231 section 4.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2), already cited in earlier comments:

> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on
> the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the same
> as the effect for a single such request. Of the request methods
> defined by this specification, PUT, DELETE, and safe request methods
> are idempotent.
>
> (...)
>
> Idempotent methods are distinguished because the request can be
> repeated automatically if a communication failure occurs before the
> client is able to read the server's response. For example, if a
> client sends a PUT request and the underlying connection is closed
> before any response is received, then the client can establish a new
> connection and retry the idempotent request. It knows that repeating
> the request will have the same intended effect, even if the original
> request succeeded, though the response might differ.

So, what should be "the same" after a repeated request of an idempotent method? Not the server state, nor the server response, but **the intended effect**. In particular, the method should be idempotent "from the point of view of the client". Now, I think that this point of view shows that the last example in [Dan Lowe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34400076/10608322), which I don't want to plagiarize here, indeed shows that a PATCH request can be non-idempotent (in a more natural way than the example in [Jason Hoetger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338329/10608322)).

Indeed, let's make the example slightly more precise by making explicit one possible **intend** for the first client. Let's say that this client goes through the list of users with the project to check their emails **and** zip codes. He starts with user 1, notices that the zip is right but the email is wrong. He decides to correct this with a PATCH request, which is fully legitimate, and sends only

```
PATCH /users/1
{"email": "skwee357@newdomain.example"}
```

since this is the only correction. Now, the request fails because of some network issue and is re-submitted automatically a couple of hours later. In the meanwhile, another client has (erroneously) modified the zip of user 1. Then, sending the same PATCH request a second time does not achieve the **intended effect** of the client, since we end up with an incorrect zip. Hence the method is not idempotent in the sense of the RFC.

If instead the client uses a PUT request to correct the email, sending to the server all properties of user 1 along with the email, his intended effect will be achieved even if the request has to be re-sent later and user 1 has been modified in the meanwhile --- since the second PUT request will overwrite all changes since the first request.

Answer (score 1):

To conclude the discussion on the idempotency, I should note that one can define idempotency in the REST context in two ways. Let's first formalize a few things:

A *resource* is a function with its co-domain being the class of strings. In other words, a resource is a subset of `String × Any`, where all the keys are unique. Let's call the class of the resources `Res`.

A REST operation on resources, is a function `f(x: Res, y: Res): Res`. Two examples of REST operations are:

- `PUT(x: Res, y: Res): Res = x`, and
- `PATCH(x: Res, y: Res): Res`, which works like `PATCH({a: 2}, {a: 1, b: 3}) == {a: 2, b: 3}`.

(This definition is specifically designed to argue about `PUT` and `POST`, and e.g. doesn't make much sense on `GET` and `POST`, as it doesn't care about persistence).

Now, by fixing `x: Res` (informatically speaking, using currying), `PUT(x: Res)` and `PATCH(x: Res)` are univariate functions of type `Res → Res`.

1. A function `g: Res → Res` is called *globally idempotent*, when `g ○ g == g`, i.e. for any `y: Res`, `g(g(y)) = g(y)`.
2. Let `x: Res` a resource, and `k = x.keys`. A function `g = f(x)` is called *left idempotent*, when for each `y: Res`, we have `g(g(y))|ₖ == g(y)|ₖ`. It basically means that the result should be same, if we look at the applied keys.

So, `PATCH(x)` is not globally idempotent, but is left idempotent. And left idempotency is the thing that matters here: if we patch a few keys of the resource, we want those keys to be same if we patch it again, and we don't care about the rest of the resource.

And when RFC is talking about PATCH not being idempotent, it is talking about global idempotency. Well, it's good that it's not globally idempotent, otherwise it would have been a broken operation.

---

Now, [Jason Hoetger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338329/2449905) is trying to demonstrate that PATCH is not even left idempotent, but it's breaking too many things to do so:

- First of all, PATCH is used on a set, although PATCH is defined to work on maps / dictionaries / key-value objects.
- If someone really wants to apply PATCH to sets, then there is a natural translation that should be used: `t: Set<T> → Map<T, Boolean>`, defined with `x in A iff t(A)(x) == True`. Using this definition, patching is left idempotent.
- In the example, this translation was not used, instead, the PATCH works like a POST. First of all, why is an ID generated for the object? And when is it generated? If the object is first compared to the elements of the set, and if no matching object is found, then the ID is generated, then again the program should work differently (`{id: 1, email: "me@site.example"}` must match with `{email: "me@site.example"}`, otherwise the program is always broken and the PATCH cannot possibly patch). If the ID is generated before checking against the set, again the program is broken.

One can make examples of PUT being non-idempotent with breaking half of the things that are broken in this example:

- An example with *generated additional features* would be versioning. One may keep record of the number of changes on a single object. In this case, PUT is not idempotent: `PUT /user/12 {email: "me@site.example"}` results in `{email: "...", version: 1}` the first time, and `{email: "...", version: 2}` the second time.
- Messing with the IDs, one may generate a new ID every time the object is updated, resulting in a non-idempotent PUT.

All the above examples are natural examples that one may encounter.

---

My final point is, that PATCH should not be *globally idempotent*, otherwise won't give you the desired effect. You want to change the email address of your user, without touching the rest of the information, and you don't want to overwrite the changes of another party accessing the same resource.

Answer (score 0):

A very nice explanation is here-

[https://blog.segunolalive.com/posts/restful-api-design-%E2%80%94-put-vs-patch/#:~:text=RFC%205789,not%20required%20to%20be%20idempotent](https://blog.segunolalive.com/posts/restful-api-design-%E2%80%94-put-vs-patch/#:%7E:text=RFC%205789,not%20required%20to%20be%20idempotent).

**A Normal Payload-**
// House on plot 1
{
address: 'plot 1',
owner: 'segun',
type: 'duplex',
color: 'green',
rooms: '5',
kitchens: '1',
windows: 20
}
**PUT For Updated-**
// PUT request payload to update windows of House on plot 1
{
address: 'plot 1',
owner: 'segun',
type: 'duplex',
color: 'green',
rooms: '5',
kitchens: '1',
windows: 21
}
Note: In above payload we are trying to update windows from 20 to 21.

Now see the PATH payload-
// Patch request payload to update windows on the House
{
windows: 21
}

Since PATCH is not idempotent, failed requests are not automatically re-attempted on the network. Also, if a PATCH request is made to a non-existent url e.g attempting to replace the front door of a non-existent building, it should simply fail without creating a new resource unlike PUT, which would create a new one using the payload. Come to think of it, it’ll be odd having a lone door at a house address.

Answer (score 0):

**PUT** method is ideal to update data in tabular format like in a relational db or entity like storage. Based on use case it can be used to update data partially or replace the entity as a whole. This will always be idempotent.

**PATCH** method can be used to update(or restructure) data in json or xml format which is stored in local file system or no sql database. This can be performed by mentioning the action/operation to be performed in the request like adding/removing/moving a key-value pair to json object. The remove operation can be used to delete a key-value pair and duplicate request will result in error as the key was deleted earlier making it a non-idempotent method. refer [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) for json data patching request.

This [artical](https://medium.com/easyread/http-patch-method-ive-thought-the-wrong-way-c62ad281cb8) has detailed information related to PATCH method.

Comment: Thanks for the artical link. I sheds an interesting light on the HTTP PATCH and JSON-PATCH congruency

Answer (score 0):

I will try to summarize in layman terms what I understood (maybe it helps)

Patch is not fully idempotent (it can be in an ideal situation where nobody changes another field of your entity).

In an not ideal (real life) situation somebody modifies another field of your object by another Patch operation and then both operations are not Idempotent (meaning that the resource you are both modifying comes back "wrong" from either one point of view)

So you cannot call it Idempotent if it does not cover 100% of the situations.
Maybe this is not that important to some, but to others is

Answer (score -1):

One additional information I just one to add is that a PATCH request use less bandwidth compared to a  PUT request  since just a part of the data is sent not the whole entity.  So just use a PATCH request for updates  of  specific records  like (1-3 records) while PUT request for updating a larger amount of data.  That is it,  don't think too much or worry about it too much.