# HTTP PATCH is idempotent or non idempotent?

Tags: rest, idempotent

I have read lots of places that HTTP Patch is non-idempotent. Can someone explain me why it is non-idempotent ? 
Because as per the definition - Idempotent methods may or may not change the resource state, but repeated requests should have no further side effects after the first request.
How a repeated PATCH request can change the Resource state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's some confusion about that. The PATCH method is not **required** to be idempotent, that's the point. Clients can't assume their PATCH requests will be idempotent, as they can do with PUT and GET.

If a particular implementation will be idempotent or not usually depends on the patching algorithm being used, if any. For instance, a poor implementation that's not using a diff format that validates the current values won't be idempotent.

Comment: Yes. Above explanation makes sense. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Sorry but you can make *non* idempotent PATCH requests even with a diff format like [JSON Patch](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902). For instance by appending items to an array: `{"op": "add", "path": "/-", "value": "foo"}` transforms `[]` to `["foo"]` the 1st time, then to `["foo", "foo"]` the 2nd time, then to `["foo", "foo", "foo"]` the 3rd time, etc.

Comment: @Maggyero "not using a diff format that **validates the current values**"

Comment: I don't see how validation relates to idempotence. Appending to an array, validated or not, will never be idempotent.

Comment: Indeed, because appending to an array is not a diff-like operation.

Comment: Really? How do you define a diff-like operation if you exclude the add operation?

Comment: Is appending an array even a PATCH operation?  That's extremely ambiguous?  Is the element we're patching a key or a name-value pair?  Is there any criteria for uniqueness?  *As long as we're talking about updating a non-array value, a patch should be considered idempotent*.  If we look at the array field as its own object then the operation could be a PUT, a POST *OR* a PATCH

Comment: Can you do it in a diff-like operation? If you can, it can be a PATCH. If you can't, it's probably a POST. PUT is to replace the entire document.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a lot of discussion & confusion how PUT and PATCH differ. The clear is:

PUT

- request must contain **whole representation** of given resource
- **is idempotent** (client can be sure for 100%)

PATCH

- request contains just **subset** (just attributes we want to update)
- **is not required to be idempotent** (quite often is idempotent, but it is not rule, so client cannot be 100% sure in this)

From those rules, we can deduce some rules we need to implement in the backend, e.g.:

a)

- GET: users/1; response body {`username: 'john', email: 'old@email.com'`}
- PUT: users/1; request body {`username: 'john'`}

Either sever send validation error from API (missing `email`) or email will be deleted.

I really hope that API should return validation error. So to delete some value, client should call (explicitly `email: null` mentioned in the request):

- PUT: users/1; request body {`username: 'john', email: null`}

b)

- PATCH: users/1; request body {`username: 'john'`}

No change on the server. To delete value, client should send:

- PATCH: users/1; request body {`email: null`}

Both examples above are idempotent.

In the other discussion is example that PATCH is non-idempotent if patch is doing something like "add" to the collection in the backend: [Use of PUT vs PATCH methods in REST API real life scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459418/use-of-put-vs-patch-methods-in-rest-api-real-life-scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

A PATCH is not necessarily idempotent, although it can be. Contrast this with PUT; which is always idempotent. The word "idempotent" means that any number of repeated, identical requests will leave the resource in the same state. For example, if an auto-incrementing counter field is an integral part of the resource, then a PUT will naturally overwrite it (since it overwrites everything), but not necessarily so for PATCH.