# REST API Subscriptions and transactions(payments) endpoints in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest, transactions, web-deployment

I am developing a web app and I observe REST API standards. I am searching for REST API best practice for subscription and payments.

When a new user subscribe for "pro plan", user should pay money for plan and it is a transaction.

Should I set POST: `users/{id}/subscriptions` and `SubscriptionsController@store` when new user subscribes?

And because subscription is a transaction and 2 separated request (before/after bank), all of subscribe codes should be in `SubscriptionController@store`?

For upgrade, cancel or updating a plan should I set PUT: `users/{id}/subscriptions/{id}` and `SubscriptionController@update` or other endpoint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST API - PUT vs PATCH with real life examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459418/rest-api-put-vs-patch-with-real-life-examples). All of your questions are answered in this comment and covered thoroughly. Please have a read through.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I read many contents about REST API. I couldn't find my answer. And in these answers also there isn't certain and best practice about my question. If you have answer please answer.

Comment: What are you mean by "because subscription is a transaction and 2 separated request (before/after bank)". Its not clear enough.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here. You can set up your own routes however you like. Is there a specific programming issue/problem you have...?

Comment: @gayan Subscribing for a specify plan need 2 request: 1- before payment for credit card info and ... . 2- after payment for validating payment. If this two request were successful, user will be subscribe for plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you would not pass the user id in the route, unless there was some sort of authentication in the controller. eg. Admin is updating the user. Instead use the `Auth::user()` object in the controller.

With regard to your question, there are many options and it is entirely up to you, but a possible way of doing it would be to use a [resource route\controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers) for this.

`Route::resource('user/subscription', 'User\SubscriptionController');`

Then the controller would look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class SubscriptionController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        // get user
        $user = Auth::user();

        // list all user subscriptions
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        // get user
        $user = Auth::user();

        if(empty($user)) {
            // create user
        }

        // create and process subscription for the user 
        // possibly using a plan id in the $request
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        // get user
        $user = Auth::user();

        // return user subscription details for $id
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // get user
        $user = Auth::user();

        // update or change user subscription
        // possibly using a plan id in the $request

    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        // get user
        $user = Auth::user();

        // cancel user subscription with $id
    }
}
```

And your routes would be like this:

`GET` `user/subscription` list all user subscriptions `index()`

`POST` `user/subscription` create a user subscription `store(Request $request)`

`GET` `user/subscription/{subscription_id}` show a user subscription `show($id)`

`PUT/PATCH` `user/subscription/{subscription_id}` update a user subscription `update($id)`

`DELETE` `user/subscription/{subscription_id}` cancel a user subscription `destroy($id)`

Comment: I use auth()->user() in my controllers. But also I get user id in route and I use it for policy. I think it is more REST friendly!

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to understand what you asking for but it's a little bit blur for me so if I got right , you are trying to figure what is the best practice for API End point naming , it's really depend on the functions you will provide and how you will expose the documentation.

But from my point I don't see a reason to chain user ID and subscriber ID in the URL , I recommend something like this and you can pass all the information you want in the body

```
$router->post('settings/user/plan', 'Settings\SubscriptionController@subscribe');
$router->put('settings/user/plan', 'Settings\SubscriptionController@changeSubscriptionPlan');
$router->delete('settings/user/plan', 'Settings\SubscriptionController@cancelSubscription');
$router->post('settings/user/plan/resume', 'Settings\SubscriptionController@resumeSubscription');
$router->put('settings/user/card', 'Settings\SubscriptionController@updateCard');
$router->put('settings/user/vat', 'Settings\SubscriptionController@updateExtraBillingInfo');
$router->get('settings/user/plan/invoice/{id}', 'Settings\SubscriptionController@downloadInvoice');
```

It's really up to you how you define your endpoints

Answer (score 1):

If your try for **Braintree or Stripe** both payment gateway through easily maintan plans and subscription.

**Main Benifits :-**

1. Less coding for subscription and plan
2. UI ready in Braintree tree drop-ui its reponsive
3. Easily attach add-ons charges