# How to implement partial update via rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Let's say we have a resourceful Student model. I have a query regarding updating a student resource via `PUT` api.

If we send a put request to `PUT /students/1` along with request body containing the few attributes that we want to update.

Let's the Student having many attributes like `name,age,rollno,country,dob` and we just want to update the `country`, so in the put request body we will pass something like `{country: 'germany'}` , some other request might pass only the `dob`.

How should we handle it in server side to only update the attributes passed in the body ?

Comment: Technically, this would want to be `PATCH` instead of `PUT`, discussed some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459418/rest-api-put-vs-patch-with-real-life-examples). If you did `resources :students`, your `update` route already supports `PUT` or `PATCH`

Answer (score 1):

The `update` method on your ActiveRecord objects takes an attributes hash. You can pass only one attribute, or all attributes of a model, and `ActiveRecord` will figure out what has changed and only update those columns and leave the rest alone.

```
student = Student.create(name: 'name', age: 'age', rollno: 'rollno', country: 'country', dob: 'dob')

params = { country: 'germany' } # stand-in for your actual params hash in the controller

student.update(params)
```

Only `country` will be updated, everything else will remain the same. On the next request when you update `dob` it works the same way.

```
params = { dob: '1/1/2000` }

student.update(params)
```

Comment: But i do not know which keys are coming in api request body.

Comment: Right, I'm just showing you how that doesn't matter. Assuming that you have parameters coming in some hash-like object, in this case the hash is stored in a variable called `params`. If you pass the hash to the `update` method you will get a partial update like you want

Comment: Your question is sort of broad, so if you're also asking how to handle the incoming params all the way through the routing and controller level then you should clarify that and read through the guides first http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy since you said you `have a resourceful Student model`, I assumed you aren't asking about routing and controllers and params hashes, and are just asking about the API to perform the actual database update : ) let me know if the answer can be improved