# Django Update Method for Viewset returning 415 even after overwritting it

Tags: python, django, rest, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

Right now I am learning to create REST API with Django, but am struggling to implement the Update method. My tests always fail and I am not sure if it is because of the serializer or something else. Would appreciate some quick feedback for my code!

```
class Company(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class JobPost(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='guest_posts')
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name')

class JobPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer(read_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = GuestPost
        fields = ('id', 'heading', 'company')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        company = Company.objects.get(title=request.data.get('company_name'))
        return GuestPost.objects.create(owner=request.user,
                                        heading=validated_data.get('heading'),
                                        company=company)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.heading = validated_data.pop('heading')
        instance.save()
        return instance

class JobPostViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet,
                     viewsets.generics.ListCreateAPIView,
                     viewsets.mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                     viewsets.mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):
    permission_classes = (JobPostPermissions,)
    serializer_class = JobPostSerializer
    queryset = JobPost.objects.all()
```

I then test this code, all my tests for the other operations (create, get, list) work but I get an error 415 when testing the update using the following method:

```
class Test(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(username="elon")
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.request_url = '/api/job-post/'
        self.boring_company = Company.objects.create(owner=self.user, title="Boring Company")
        self.job_post = JobPost.objects.create(company=self.boring_company, heading="Looking for boring person")
        self.sample_uuid = self.job_post.id

    def test_update_post(self):
        data = {
            'id': self.sample_uuid,
            'heading': 'New Heading',
            'description': 'new description',
        }
        request = self.factory.put(self.request_url, data=data)
        view = GuestPostViewSet.as_view({'put': 'update'})
        force_authenticate(request, user=self.user)
        response = view(request, pk=self.sample_uuid)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['heading'], 'New Heading')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `GuestPost` model?

Comment: Dumb question. Can you reproduce the same issue hitting your API with a REST client? Just wondering whether it is an error in the code or the tests.

Comment: You were right it was the test.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the answer after a second look at the [Django Rest docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/). As others have pointed out, it was the test that was the problem. Here is the official example of what you need to do for update requests:

```
from django.test.client import encode_multipart, RequestFactory

factory = RequestFactory()
data = {'title': 'remember to email dave'}
content = encode_multipart('BoUnDaRyStRiNg', data)
content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=BoUnDaRyStRiNg'
request = factory.put('/notes/547/', content, content_type=content_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `415` response refers to [`Unsupported Media Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415), so it indicates that the payload you are sending to server is not valid to server. As far as I know, when you are sending a `put` request, you must put the whole `model` in your request! (for more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34400076/8342406)) And as I can see here, you are missing the `company` in your request payload (`data` dictionary in your code) However I don't know what is inside `GuestPostViewSet` but I can guess it would use `JobPostSerializer` as its serializer which have `'company'` in the `fields` tuple of its `Meta` class!

For updating a model without sending the whole attributes of it, you can use `patch` request instead. So change request type and view in your test class:

```
request = self.factory.patch(self.request_url, data=data)
```

...

```
view = GuestPostViewSet.as_view({'patch': 'update'})
```