# ASP.NET Core Web API with Entity Framework Core default scaffolded controller confuses put and post?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an ASP.NET Core Web API project with Entity Framework Core and scaffolded a new "API controller with actions, using Entity Framework" and, while it's wonderful, I get the feeling the default `PUT` and `POST` methods are swapped and would like some feedback on the matter:

```
    // PUT: api/Items/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutItem(long id, Item Item)
    {
        if (id != Item.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(Item).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ItemExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Items
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Item>> PostItem(Item Item)
    {
        _context.Items.Add(Item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetItem), new { id = Item.Id }, Item);
    }

    private bool ItemExists(long id)
    {
        return _context.Items.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }
```

As far as I know `PUT` should provide an object to be added to the database, while `PATCH` should be used to update an existing object. But from what I see in this code `PUT` is being used to update an already existing item, specifying an id that must already exist, while `POST` just uploads a new resource, without specifying any id, how I imagine a `PUT` should work.

Am I wrong or should I swap the `HttpPut` for `HttpPatch` and the `HttpPost` for `HttpPut`?

Comment: In general in rest API, `POST` is to create, `PUT` to modify an entire existing object using its id and `PATCH` to modify only some fields of the object, also by using its id. There is a lot more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28459418/3797799

Comment: There's no confusion. POST creates, PUT updates. That's what those two methods do too.  This PUT updates the stored record with the contents of the `Item` object. To do that, it attaches the object to the DbContext in the `Modified` state. EF will generate a SQL query that updates all fields using the values in `Item`'s properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PUT to create or update a resource which you know its URL. So consider the URL is  `/user/123` if there exists an object in that position, the PUT will simply update the data, if not the request will create a new user under path `/user/123`.

If you wish to update the object entirely (i.e. all its fields) you use PUT, if you want to update a single field of the resource, go for PATCH.

Whereas POST method is used to add a new resource which you don't know its URL. So you're request URL will be `/user` as you don't know the target.

Hope this helps!