# REST conventions for URI

Tags: rest, uri

At work, I've seen routes like this:

```
/people/:id/edit
```

But I reckon such routes are hard to build programmatically. To my mind, better, is:

```
/people/edit/:id
```

That way, you can do stuff like:

```
const peopleEditRoute = '/people/edit'
...
<Route path=`${peopleEditRoute}/:id`
...
<Link to=`${peopleEditRoute)/${id}`
```

However, a colleague commented that *'/peoples/:id/edit' is more conventional - it follows REST*

Are they right?

Comment: Your colleague is not right; the convention for updating a resource is a `PATCH` or `PUT` (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28459418/3001761) to `/people/:id`. But then `/people/edit/:id` isn't right either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @jonrsharpe's comment, the route should be:

```
/people/:id
```

...for all of GET, POST, PATCH etc...

Answer (score 0):

> /peoples/:id/edit' is more conventional - it follows REST
> Are they right?

No; REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

> I reckon such routes are hard to build programmatically.

They shouldn't be.  [URI Templates](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570) are a common solution, and I would expect library support in most languages where you are likely to be writing web code.  (Hint: do you really want to be writing your own logic for deciding when to encode your data?)

---

One consideration for path segments is [relative resolution](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-5.2): in particular the use of [dot segments](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) to move around an identifier hierarchy.

In other words, if you are in the context of the edit resource for some person, are you more likely to want a relative reference to another resource for the same person, or to the edit resource of a different person?

---

As noted by @jonrsharpe, if you are creating an API that is "of the web", then you typically will request the modification of a resource by sending a request  (PATCH/POST/PUT) that identifies that resource as the request target.

The point here is [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons).  Caching is a constraint in the [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4), and general purpose HTTP components know that responses can be re-used to service other requests, and know that successful unsafe requests invalidate previously cached responses.